# When does it make sense to use Items over controller or model variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Asp.net mvc provides the ability to have page specific variables in the form of Items. These persist across action actions you might jump through during the processing of your view.

I'm a bit confused right now though because while using them can make things easier, it can also lead to weird dependency scenarios like the one i'm facing right now where in one action I am forced to call another action (in my case unnecessarily) before I can proceed in the former action.

Also asp.net provides the ability to either bind arguments to a model as well as pass them straight into an action when you execute a controller action. This way each action can operate with a set of variables specific to it's needs.

With those alternative methods in mind, it seems like the ideal thing would be to use a model or action specific variables per action instead of using Item values that persists across all actions. Regardless, Items still exist...

Are Item variables just a relic from asp.net (prior to mvc) and should now be avoided in MVC? Otherwise, Can anyone help me understand scenarios where using an item variable might make more sense than just declaring the variables important for the action directly in the model or on the controller action?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to `HttpContext.Items`?

Comment: If you need to call an action just to initialize some variables, then the variable initialization would need to be pulled off of the action and put in a separate method than can then be called by who ever needs it.

Comment: @Amy yes the "Items" i'm referring to are referenced with HttpContext.Items or HttpContext.Current.Items depending on the scenario.

Comment: Yes, that collection pre-dates MVC and goes *allllllll* the way back to ASP.Net Webforms.  The *idea* for `Items` goes back further than that, back to Classic ASP, which had a `Session` object that could hold a collection of arbitrary items.

Comment: @Amy that's what I'm thinking. I mean session makes sense right because it allows a typically stateless process to now have state. Accounts couldn't operate as easily w/o it. But items ... I mean the program i'm working on uses it cause it's typically been easy to manage but I'm seeing these problems that are a direct cause of the use of them and i'm thinking... at least the way they're using it, doesn't make sense.

Comment: @misterbee180 By `Accounts`, what are you referring to exactly?  Do you mean the model used to represent the current user?  This is a matter of personal opinion, but my two cents says you should only use the `Items` collection if nothing MVC-specific exists that can do the same job.

Comment: @Amy the model I'm referring to in this case is a search object model... but the way I structured the question was really representing any model / or situation in general. Ultimately I'm just trying to figure out if use of Items is an indicator of a scenario that could be made better or if there's scenarios where Items collection usage makes more sense than anything else.

Comment: @misterbee180 I've used that `Items` collection *once* in like the last 10 years.  The IIS URL-Rewrite module sets an item in that collection called `IIS_WasUrlRewritten` with a value defining, well, what its name implies.  It sets the value in that collection because its not an MVC-specific module, it applies to all of ASP.Net.  MVC has some components in the framework, such as `Url.Content()` that look for that particular item when generating urls, routes and the like.

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario I thought of where use of item might make some sense is in the case where encapsulate some functionality into a separate action simply to reduce complexity of the originating code. In this case you can't easily define variables that you need back in the previous action. So you can just set them up as item values and they are now accessible in the former action after the subsequent action fully completes.

This should work work as long as there's never a scenario where you choose not to call the secondary function.

This is definitely a special circumstance though as the secondary action should need access to the detail being passed back. Otherwise it'd make sense to just pull the logic out of the secondary action and apply it to the former action.